# How to open online csv file?

Tags: python, csv

Here is the [link](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine-quality/winequality-red.csv) of the csv file. The problem is I have no idea on how to open it and do something on this set of data.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = 'http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine-quality/winequality-red.csv'
x = urlopen(url)
data = x.read()
```

I wanna create the column index by myself:

```
names = []
firstLine = True
for line in data:
    if firstLine:
        names = line.strip().split(';')
        firstLine = False
```

However, the result of names is [' " '] which is not I expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pandas for this:

```
import pandas as pd
url = 'http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine-quality/winequality-red.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url, sep=';')
```

Comment: Appreciate that. But using pandas would automatically treat the first row as the index while I would rather prefer to do it on my own.

Comment: you can add the argument `header=None` to make sure that the first row is not becoming the column names (not the index)

Comment: fantastic, it works. It looks pandas is still the best option to handle data though I'm looking for my own way to achieve the same output.

Answer (score 1):

When you read your file (`data = x.read()`), then you getting binary object, you just need decode it to utf-8:

```
text = data.decode('utf-8')
```

then you need use StringIO and csv for read this data:

```
import csv, io
reader = csv.reader(io.StringIO(text), csv.excel)
```

and now the reader is just a list with your data from file

Comment: I've tried this one before but what's the next move if I wanna extract the first row as the column index?

Comment: it shows 'list' object has no attribute 'split' when I run my code.

Comment: yep, coz list object don't have this method, you can split only strings.

Comment: [['6.3;0.51;0.13;2.3;0.076;29;40;0.99574;3.42;0.75;11;6']
['5.9;0.645;0.12;2;0.075;32;44;0.99547;3.57;0.71;10.2;5']
['6;0.31;0.47;3.6;0.067;18;42;0.99549;3.39;0.66;11;6']
]

Answer (score 1):

With `csv` this can be done as follows:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import csv
import io

url = 'http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine-quality/winequality-red.csv'
x = urlopen(url)
csv_data = x.read().decode('utf-8')
csv_input = csv.reader(io.StringIO(csv_data), delimiter=';')
header = next(csv_input)

print("Header is:", header)
data = list(csv_input)

# Display start of data
for row in data[:5]:
    print(row)
```

Which would give you:

```
Header is: ['fixed acidity', 'volatile acidity', 'citric acid', 'residual sugar', 'chlorides', 'free sulfur dioxide', 'total sulfur dioxide', 'density', 'pH', 'sulphates', 'alcohol', 'quality']
['7.4', '0.7', '0', '1.9', '0.076', '11', '34', '0.9978', '3.51', '0.56', '9.4', '5']
['7.8', '0.88', '0', '2.6', '0.098', '25', '67', '0.9968', '3.2', '0.68', '9.8', '5']
['7.8', '0.76', '0.04', '2.3', '0.092', '15', '54', '0.997', '3.26', '0.65', '9.8', '5']
['11.2', '0.28', '0.56', '1.9', '0.075', '17', '60', '0.998', '3.16', '0.58', '9.8', '6']
['7.4', '0.7', '0', '1.9', '0.076', '11', '34', '0.9978', '3.51', '0.56', '9.4', '5']
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code fetches the csv file and saves it into your current directory

```
from urllib.request import urlretrieve

url = 'http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine-quality/winequality-red.csv'

urlretrieve(url, 'wine.csv')
```

and then you can read it, in a dataframe

```
df = pd.read_csv('wine.csv', delimiter=';')
```